# Angular return url is null

Tags: angular

In my application if personel is not logged in goes to login with return url

```
 this.user=this._session.getEmployee();
 if(!this.user){
    this.router.navigate(['PA/Login'], {queryParams: {returnUrl:this.url}});
 }
```

and in login component in `ngOnInit` I'm trying to reach with code below.
in costructor I declared `private route: ActivatedRoute`

```
this.url=this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('returnUrl');
```

this is my route configuration

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:"",redirectTo:"PA/Login",pathMatch:"full"},
  {path:"PA",redirectTo:"PA/Login",pathMatch:"full"},
  {path:"PA/Home",component:HomeComponent}, 
  {path:"PA/Email/:url",component:EmailComponent}, 
  {path:"PA/Login",component:LoginComponent}, 
  {path:"PA/Login?returnUrl=:returnUrl",component:LoginComponent}, 
];
```

but it returns null. Where do I make mistake?

Thanks for you helps

Comment: Can you post your router configuration?

Comment: I put it in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get the **query params** from `paramMap`, when you should get through [**`queryParamMap`**](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#queryParamMap):

```
this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('returnUrl');
```

Also, you don't need the following line in router config:

`{path:"PA/Login?returnUrl=:returnUrl",component:LoginComponent},`